# Does the 1-D poisson's equation have monotonic potentials if $\rho=\rho(\phi(z))$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, plasma-physics

I am solving the 1-D poisson equation:

$$\frac{d^2 \phi}{dz^2}=-4\pi\rho(\phi)$$

with the additional requirement that $\rho(\phi(z=0))=0$. If I start by multiplying each side by $\frac{d\phi}{d z}$ and integrate from 0 to $\phi '$ I get

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2=-4\pi\int_0^{\phi '}\rho(\phi) \frac{d\phi}{d z} dz$$

so I have

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2=-4\pi\int_0^{\phi '}\rho(\phi) d\phi$$

Because of the square on the left hand side I will only get solutions when the right hand side is positive. I find this requirement odd because you will always get that the derivative of the potential never changes sign and is always monotonic when the charge density is written in the form $\rho(\phi)$. Am I doing something wrong here or have I misinterpreted the result?

More specifically If I provide a charge density that changes sign with $\phi$ will I be unsuccessful in finding a solution?

Also for anyone who is familiar with it, this first series of steps is used in the derivation of the Child-Langmuir law for the thickness of a plasma sheath, but in the ion sheath problem $\rho$ does not change sign (See the Bohm Criterion if interested).

Comment: Hint to the question (v1): If we assume the first equation, then there is missing an integration 'constant' in the second eq. Phrased equivalently: The lower limit of the antiderivative is missing.

Comment: If I have a definite integral why is there an integration constant?

Comment: Ah I probably forgot to mention that $\rho(0)=0$ I'll change it.

Comment: No need to assume $\rho(0)=0$. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Last time I did this in class we multiplied by $d\phi/dz$ and integrated by parts so after that the LHS should be $1/2 [(d\phi/dz)^2_{\phi=\phi'}-(d\phi/dz)^2_{\phi=0}]$

Comment: For $\rho(\phi):=0$ the solution is $\phi(z)=a·z+b$ and the equation reads $0=0$. You say you "integrate up" and end up with $\frac{1}{2}a^2=0$. Magic.

Comment: This is not Poisson equation. In Poisson equation $\rho$ is a given function and not a function of $\phi$.

Comment: @NikolajK The requirement was not $\rho(\phi)=0$ it was  $\rho(\phi=0)=0$

Comment: @Anode: So? $\rho(\phi):=0$ fulfills $\rho(\phi=0)=0$. So I'm pointing out that for the trivial case, the concluded relation is already broken. That's a general tool for investigating mathematics: If you're skeptical of a result obtained with free parameters, go back and choose particular examples for those parameters to see at which point in the derivation the system breaks down.

Comment: @V.Moretti $\phi$ is a free function of z that I am solving for given a charge density that is dependent on the potential.

Comment: @NikolajK Which concluded relation is broken? In the trivial case \rho does not change sign. It's no surprise that $\phi(z)=0$ in your example.

Comment: Let me expand on [Qmechanic's comment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99879/does-the-1-d-poissons-equation-have-monotonic-potentials-if-rho-rho-phi#comment203797_99879): $$\int_0^{z_0} \frac{d}{dz}\left( \frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2 dz \neq \left(\frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2$$ Instead $$\int_0^{z_0} \frac{d}{dz}\left( \frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2 dz = \left(\frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2 \Big|_0^{z_0}$$The "wrong" expression looks "manifestly positive". The correct one doesn't.

Comment: @WillieWong Isn't this what I wrote in a previous comment?

Comment: @Anode: no. You evaluated at $\phi = 0$, which is nonsense. Integrating a derivative in $z$ you should evaluate at $z = z_0$ and $z = 0$. Incidentally it also makes your choice of upper bound of integration "$\phi'$" look very bizarre. (Also, at this level it is a problem with _calculus_, and has relatively little to do with _physics_.)

Comment: @WillieWong Ah I see the issue. I should have written $\rho(\phi(z=0))=0$.

Comment: @Anode: "It's no surprise that $\phi(z)=0$ in your example." What do you mean by that? The solution is $\phi(z)=a·z+b$ and these are valid for all $a,b$. The conclusion you should draw isn't that $\phi(z)=0$ follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system solves the Euler-Lagrange equations of the Lagrangian:
$$L\left(\phi, \frac{d\phi}{dz}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2 - 4\pi \int_0^{\phi(z)} \rho(s) ds$$
since the corresponding Lagrange equations are:
$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dz^2}= -4\pi \rho(\phi)\:.$$ 
As the Lagrangian does not explicitly depend on "time" $z$, "energy" is conserved along the solutions (varying $z$):
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2 + 4\pi \int_0^{\phi(z)} \rho(s) ds =E\:.$$
The constant $E$ can be determined from the initial conditions, e.g.  $\phi(0)$ and $d\phi/dz|_{z=0}$. Once $E$ has been fixed, the equation becomes:
$$\frac{d\phi}{dz} = \pm \sqrt{2E - 8\pi  \int_0^{\phi(z)} \rho(s) ds}\:.$$
The sign, once again can be fixed from the initial condition since it is the one of $d\phi/dz|_{z=0}$.

It seems to me that, at least locally, that equation can always be solved if $\rho$ is continuous, unless $d\phi/dz|_{z=0}=0$, situation which needs great care since the RHS (while it keeps being continuous) is not locally Lipschitz around the corresponding initial condition  $\phi(0)$.

Comment: is the sign in the first line supposed to be a +?

Comment: Maybe I took a mistake with signs, but I do not think so: $d/dz( \partial L /\partial (d\phi/dz) )= \partial L/ \partial \phi$ produces your equation...